Why am I getting the error "Service 'security.route_loader.logout' not found" in Symfony, even though I have defined it in my security.yaml?
I am facing the following error:
Service "security.route_loader.logout" not found: The container inside "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "kernel" service in security.route_loader.logout (which is being imported from "/Path/To/Project/config/routes/security.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "service" type.

I can't figure out what I need to do to resolve this error.
Here is my configuration:
config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER ]
        ROLE_MODERATOR: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN ]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4
                time_cost: 3
                memory_cost: 10

config/routes/security.yaml
_security_logout:
    resource: security.route_loader.logout
    type: service

config/services.yaml
parameters:

services:
    App\EventListener\ThemeRequestListener:
        tags:
            - { name: ThemeRequestListener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }

    App\EventSubscriber\EmployeeEventSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    security.route_loader.logout:
        class: App\Security\AppAuthenticator

    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

I tried multiple times to modify one of the YAML files accordingly, but nothing worked. :(
